# Display startup picture - Android app

Tags: android

I want to add a fullscreen image view when the app is opened. For example, In Flipkart app, you can see it will display a picture and then only enters into the homepage. Like that i want to display a picture in my app. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This site if for help you with parts of codes or issues with it and not for full implementations. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

It is known as Splash Screen you can create it as a Splash screen activity. try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)